# Thunar Disable video Thumbnails only

Tags: video, xfce, thunar, thumbnails

Is there a way in Thunar (within XFCE) to disable displaying of Video thumbnails only and still allow Picture thumbnails?

I found this thread:
[Show me only picture thumbnails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134210/show-me-only-picture-thumbnails)

But that is for Nautilus and I cannot find Thunar in that list anywhere. Or preferrably only remote videos, Nautilus used to only thumbnail local videos not remote. So if disabling for only remote is possible that would be better.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is also now an officially recommended way to manage which thumbnails are generated in `Thunar` by `tumbler`, the Xfce thumbnailing service. Using the method described below means nothing will need to be uninstalled from the `gstreamer` set of packages, and all other thumbnails (apart from video) will be generated.

**However**, it is important to note that this is only possible if you have `tumbler` 0.1.27, although this will be at least [the version in Raring (13.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/tumbler). If you are on Xubuntu 12.10, you only need to enable the [Xfce 4.12 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12) to get the latest version of `tumbler`.

On the Xfce [announce mailing lists](http://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-announce/2013-January/000244.html) for January 2013, it was noted that, regarding `tumbler` 0.1.27,

> This release ships a config file installed in the xdg directory to
>   control the various plugins (especially the priority). There is also a
>   cover download plugin (dependency is libcurl), but this has been
>   disabled by default.

How to enable and disable various plugins is explained [on the Xfce official page](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler), but briefly here's how it works. As noted in the explanation, if you want to customise the tumbler rc file, you can make a `tumbler` folder in your  user-specific configuration folder and then copy `tumbler.rc` from `/etc/xdg/tumbler` to that folder:

```
cd ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}
mkdir -p tumbler
cd tumbler
cp /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc .
```

Now, edit the file with your preferred text editor, e.g.

```
gedit tumbler.rc
```

and you will see something like [this sample rc file](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/tumbler/plain/tumblerd/tumbler.rc), which has sections for video, image and other thumbnailer plugins.

As an example, you could find the section `Video Thumbnailers` in the file above and set `Disabled=true` in the sections for the `ffmpegthumbnailer` and the `gstreamer` plugins. Using this method you do not have to remove `gstreamer0.10-plugins` to stop video thumbnails being shown.

Excerpt from the `Video Thumbnailers` section of `tumbler.rc`:

```
# ffmpegthumbnailer plugin
[FfmegThumbnailer]
Disabled=true
Priority=2
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0

# GStreamer plugin
[GstThumbnailer]
Disabled=true
Priority=1
Locations=
MaxFileSize=0
```

If at some later point you find that you do not want to entirely disable the video plugins, you could instead use `Disabled=false` to re-enable them and set a value for the `MaxFileSize`, so that only files up to a certain size were shown. This would solve problems with high memory usage when thumbnails for very large files are being generated.

- **Note**: after making any changes to `tumbler.rc` , it is crucial that you **log out** and log in again. Video thumbnailing for those two plugins, for example, would not be disabled until you logged in again.
- **Remember**, this will only work if you have `tumbler 0.1.27` or a later version installed.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 18.04 (and possibly earlier versions as well), you will also need to disable the `[DesktopThumbnailer]` plugin in order to fully disable video thumbnails from being created.

Comment: I do not have `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set.

Comment: so I have to use `$HOME/.config` instead according to [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Comment: The xfce docs seem to have removed the version agnostic link. Here is one for version 4.16 https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/4.16/tumbler

Comment: With GNOME and XFCE floating around, these steps did not work for me, but at least this one did: https://hecticgeek.com/generate-video-thumbnails-faster-ffmpegthumbnailer-cinnamon/: renaming to `/usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer.disabled`!

Answer (score 1):

open your `synaptic package manager` and remove `gstreamer0.10-plugins` and `ffmpegthumbnailer` packages . I am not sure which packages installation causes this problem to you but Thumbnail generation will done due to because of this two packages only .

so remove the one which is installed in your system and synaptic is the easy way .

hope that helps .